# Check if the first column in text file is non-empty

Tags: bash

file1.txt contains:

```
aaa:fg
aa:dfg
```

This command will give `aaa` and `aa` but I am not sure how to check if it is nonempty. I prefer to not use `awk`.

```
cut -f1 -d: file1.txt
```

Comment: It would be useful if you included a sample input containing some empty first columns, along with the corresponding desired output. Awk is a good choice for this task.

Comment: try: cut -f1 -d: file1.txt | grep -v ^$  or   cut -f1 -d: file1.txt | grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$'

Comment: what should happen if it's empty?  For any record or for the complete file?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    (( n++ ))
    [[ -z $(cut -d: -f1 <<< "${line}") ]] && printf "Line-%s empty: %s\n" "$n" "$line"
done
```

which given a file like:

```
aaa:bbb
:ccc
ddd:eee
fff:ggg
:
```

when run:

```
./my.sh < file
```

produces:

```
Line-2 empty: :ccc
Line-5 empty: :
```

Comment: Why not simply `grep '^:' file`? I expect it will be an order of magnitude faster - maybe two.

Comment: You could avoid all the `cut` calls by doing `while IFS=: read -r f1 rest` and making the test `[[ -z $f1 ]]`.